# How to upload file using a record insert wizard? Dreamweaver php

Tags: php, html, mysql, dreamweaver

Here is the code php for insert

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO siswa (NISN, Kode_KK, Nama_Siswa, Alamat_Siswa, Tgl_Lahir, Foto_siswa) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['NISN'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Kode_KK'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Nama_Siswa'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Alamat_Siswa'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Tgl_Lahir'], "date"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Foto_siswa'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_praukkcon, $praukkcon);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $praukkcon) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

And here is my insert form code

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table width="490" height="308" align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td height="24" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap><div align="center">NISN:</div></td>
      <td valign="middle"><input type="text" name="NISN" value="MAKS 10" size="32" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'MAKS 10';}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td height="24" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap><div align="center">Kode_KK:</div></td>
      <td valign="middle"><input type="text" name="Kode_KK" value="MAKS 4" size="32" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'MAKS 4';}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td height="24" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap><div align="center">Nama_Siswa:</div></td>
      <td valign="middle"><input type="text" name="Nama_Siswa" value="MAKS 50" size="32" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'MAKS 50';}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td height="24" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap><div align="center">Alamat_Siswa:</div></td>
      <td valign="middle"><input type="text" name="Alamat_Siswa" value="" size="32">      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td height="24" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap><div align="center">Tgl_Lahir:</div></td>
      <td valign="middle"><input type="text" name="Tgl_Lahir" value="YYYY-MM-DD" size="32" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'YYYY-MM-DD';}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td height="24" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap><div align="center">Foto_siswa:</div></td>
      <td valign="middle"><input type="file" name="Foto_siswa" value="" size="32">      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td height="26" align="right" valign="middle" nowrap><div align="center"></div></td>
      <td valign="middle"><div align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="INSERT DATA">
      </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
</form>
```

That's all, if youre wondering where is the connection code, i use this form using include. so the connection function is in the main page.

Comment: I'm wondering what the issue is with your current code; also DW functions are usually out dated. Are you using the `mysql_` functions?

Comment: i want to upload file but i dont know where and what to put. i search all in internet but they use their own insert code. what i use is record insert wizard.

Comment: the file is image type. so i need it to be stored in specific folder. i just dont know the code to do that. the only thing that's stored is the name of the file.  But the exact file is not there in the folder

Comment: Sorry to tell you this but the `record insert wizard` died long ago. You should use `PDO` or `mysqli`, and look at a tutorial from the past 3 years.

Comment: im still a newbie. and I'm using dreamweaver cs6. Please help me. cause it's a project that i should present in front of my teacher.

Comment: Really that still exists in CS6? Glad I haven't updated from cs4. In any event you should really look at some tutorials and ask about a specific issue you are having this is too broad as is.

Comment: most tutorials make their own insert record. i cant follow up to that. most of them actually. except there's one question i found similir to mine. but it doesnt solve my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035677/mysql-php-with-upload-file-insert-record-to-database  it gives the error column 'photo' cannot be null

Comment: Well `error column 'photo' cannot be nul`` can be solved by changing the db scheme so photo allows null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try this code, please make sure you will understand commented instruction to upload files.
1: when ever using file uploader first we mast use enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag.

2: Files are retrieved after post using $_FILES array not $_POST

3: We can save file directly in DB or a directory

i: If you are saving files directly in db then you should use blob datatype in db column name.

ii: If you are saving file in a directory and save its name in db. [I explain same thing in your code]

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {

function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{

  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {

    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);


  switch ($theType) {

    case "text":

      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";

      break;    

    case "long":

    case "int":

      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";

      break;

    case "double":

      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";

break;
    case "date":

      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";

      break;

    case "defined":

$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;

break;

  }

  return $theValue;

}

}


$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {

  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

}


if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {

 //Here First upload a files in physical(drive) location

 $_FileNameToSave = ''; //If file is not uploaded then initialize it value balnk

 $target_file = '/fileuploader'; //put here your uploaded directory name or create a folder "fileuploader" in your project root directory

  if($_FILES['Foto_siswa']['name'] && sizeof($_FILES['Foto_siswa']['name']) > 0) {

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Foto_siswa"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
{

            $_FileNameToSave = $_FILES['Foto_siswa']['name'];

        }

  }

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO siswa (NISN, Kode_KK, Nama_Siswa, Alamat_Siswa, Tgl_Lahir, Foto_siswa) 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",

GetSQLValueString($_POST['NISN'], "int"),

GetSQLValueString($_POST['Kode_KK'], "int"),

GetSQLValueString($_POST['Nama_Siswa'], "text"),

                      GetSQLValueString($_POST['Alamat_Siswa'], "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Tgl_Lahir'], "date"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_FileNameToSave, "text"));//file name to save in db


  mysql_select_db($database_praukkcon, $praukkcon);

  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $praukkcon) or die(mysql_error());

}

?>
```

Comment: Illegal string offset 'Foto_siswa' in ... what should I do next?

Comment: now this comes out  :  Warning: move_uploaded_file(/foto): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\praukk\admin\Insert\insertsiswa.php on line 45

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php6F85.tmp' to '/foto' in C:\xampp\htdocs\praukk\admin\Insert\insertsiswa.php on line 45
Column 'Foto_siswa' cannot be null

Comment: I change already the datatype to blob. Also im uploading file through this insert. not directly put the the file on a folder

Comment: If you want to upload in /foto folder give that folder 777 permission. Let me know are you using windows or linux system?